# min and max with Python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, numpy

I have an `array` and I want to generate another `array` with the `max()` values from the first `array` and zero. **See code below**:

```
lac = np.array([[-1, 2, 3]])
lacc = np.zeros((1,3))
lacc[0,:] = max(lac[0,:],0)
```

Ideally lacc should be `np.array([[0, 2, 3]])` (as would be the case in MATLAB), but here I am receiving an error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

What would be the best way without having to run a loop over every element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.maximum`:

lacc = np.maximum(lac,0)